# Consequences of Using Unstandardised Residuals Versus Standardised Residuals for Diagnostic Plots

Tags: anova, data-visualization, residuals, standardization, diagnostic

In introducing unstandardised residuals and standardised residuals for diagnostic plots, my instructor said the following:

> Using the unstandardised residuals is usually of little consequence in
>   diagnostic plots.

Why is this the case?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.